# Visual's material update from ModelPlugin in ROS Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I'm new to ROS/Gazebo so excuse me for lame words, terms and my English... and Hi everybody here, it's my first post!

I need to update link's visual material in ModelPlugin depending on some conditions (for example, when switch is up I need to assign Gazebo/GreenGlow to the visual, when it is down then Gazebo/Grey). Can this be achieved from the code ? I tried to update SDF parameters (link->GetSDF()) - I changed  to necessary value but this works only once (on gazebo gui startup). After gui is shown gazebo does not update visual using current SDF values without explicit request. So I tried to call link->UpdateParameters(sdf) with an updated sdf but got only this message in the console:

*Service call failed: transport error completing service call: unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 1019, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gazebo /home/ubuntu/work/robonaut2_taskboard_controller/stacks/nasa_r2_simulator/r2_gazebo/gazebo/r2_empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/48332fd8-7695-11e2-9689-080027b96a58/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/48332fd8-7695-11e2-9689-080027b96a58/gazebo-2*.log*

I would greatly appreciate any help on this question.
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1377/visual%27s-material-update-from-modelplugin-in-ros-gazebo/) by [Artem](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/214/artem/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-02-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, the gazebo api is very powerful and well designed.

I try to solve the problem using a VisualPlugin. The ModelPlugins exist to access the physics features of a Model. Nowadays the tutorials says that exists four kind of plugins: World, Model, Sensor and System. But the VisualPlugin exists too, I don't know if there is no documentation about it.

Well I copy the code of "ModelPush" plugin example and modify to do a visual plugin that changes the color of a box. [my_plugin.h](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/1361041844100905.h) and [my_plugin.cpp](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/1361041893450122.cpp) and finally the world file [teste.world](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/13610419305261473.world).

I don't know if there is another solution, this one is a little complicated, but maybe it serves you.

After you compile the code and run the gazebo with the world file, you should see a static box that changes the color between red and black.

If you need to change the color of things dynamically probably you need some custom messages to communicate a "physical event" to the visual plugin.

I hope that answer helps you.

---

Well there is an example in folder examples/plugins/model_visuals of gazebo source. Take a look: [Example passing a message](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/ff38b1f7b7a8d8decbdadc33a84a83eb7cc44b47/examples/plugins/model_visuals/model_visuals.cc?at=default)

This way is the correct way, I think. Once you known the visual name that you need to modify, you just need to create a visual message and sends it to gazebo. The advantage is that you can keep entire code in the ModelPlugin and modify the visuals through messages.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Vaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/171/daniel-vaz/) with karma: 305 on 2013-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6